# Windows manual driver setup : how to select a file instead of a folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, setup

I want to setup a specific driver that I downloaded and after extracting the archive I have a folder. The instructions on the website I downloaded the driver from say that, when selecting the folder in which there's the driver, I have to select the HCLASSIC.inf file. However, I can't select a file, only the folder. And when I try to setup the driver by selecting the folder only, Windows tells me that there's no driver in this folder.

Does anyone know how can I select this HCLASSIC.inf file ?

Comment: When you select a folder Windows will scan it for all compatible drivers and list them. If it says there are no compatible drivers, then you probably have incorrect driver.

Comment: @Pollux Can you post the contents of the HCLASSIC.inf file in your question?

Comment: @Pollux - Based on what you describe the driver you have is not for the device your trying to install.

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you try to add a driver manually to Windows, you have to specify a folder. Windows will search the folder for an inf that has information on what device it supports and if it supports the current OS. If Windows finds an INF that declares a compatible driver, it will store the .sys file mentioned in the INF along with the INF in DriverStore folder for future use.

In your case the INF may not have the correct entries and hence Windows is not detecting the driver.